# Upload image using SignalR in asp.net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

how can we upload images Using SignalR in asp.net MVC 
i am new on it Please help me out this how we can upload and download images from SignalR chat app.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no out-of-the-box method for this.

You can do that, but little more efforts are required. To achieve that you would be needing below steps:

1) First you need a server where you upload a file. For this make upload file service to send byte data (Uploading byte data tutorials can be found over google).

2) Once you upload file via web service, on success it should return the path of the server and file name (where that was saved on server).

3) After getting the path send this path as simple message (As you are already sending simple text message with Signal R). And add additional property to differentiate between normal text message of media message.

4) On receiving side (second user whom you are chatting with) check if the message has that additional property (which you added in previous step). If additional property is found, use that URL or file path to download the image from server and save it locally.